# Неверный интерпретатор: Нет такого файла или каталога

Tags: python, python-3.x

Драсьте, уважаемые знатоки х)

```
bash: ./2.py: /usr/bin/python: неверный интерпретатор: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

Этого файла и правда нет, однако есть такие: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при их использовании выдает следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./2.py", line 22, in <module>
    json=loads(c[n-1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double 
quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Это скрипт для вычленения из текста IP адресов. Если нужно будет его приложить, приложу, но ругается он в первую очередь на 1-ую строчку. Очень надеюсь на помощь, ибо вариантов больше нет. С env python та же байда.

Сам скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*-coding: utf-8-*-
import sys 
import argparse
import json
from json import loads
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c", "--Column", type=int, help="Номер колонки") 
parser.add_argument("-k", "--Key", help="Ключ для поиска") 
parser.add_argument("-f", "--File", help="Имя файла") 
args=parser.parse_args()
f=sys.stdin 
try:
    f=open(sys.argv[6])
except IndexError:
    print("Выполнение через конвейер")
finally:
    for line in f:
        c=line.split("\t")
        n=int(args.Column)
        if len(c) >= n:
            json=loads(c[n-1])
            if args.Key in json.keys(): 
                print(json[args.Key])
```

Comment: значит нужно писать `/usr/bin/python3`. А еще лучше - `/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: Уже пробовал. Выдает байду с последнего скрина.

Comment: На последнем скрине - ошибка `json.loads`, то есть, с интерпретатором все в порядке. И интерпретатор английским по белому пишет, в чем ошибка - неверный тип кавычек в данных для `json`. Я бы рекомендовал в вопрос поместить ваш код. Причем, и код и ошибки лучше помещать в виде текста, а не картинки. Для удобства других пользователей.

Comment: @strawdog Добавил код и ошибку, как вы посоветовали.

Comment: Приведите реальный пример, что у вас получается в `c=line.split("\t")` (выведите переменную на печать). json ругается именно на неправильно "закавыченные" данные.